# search core data without fetch all rows

Tags: search, core-data, large-data

I have Core Data with +2 millions of rows and i want to search for two specific fields: name & phone (for example). I insert scopes for each field in the Search Bar. Everything go fine if I haven't large data set. That's why I want to search in my core data without load all rows in memory before go search controller. Just need a result when my search text length > 3 or when the Search Button Clicked.

1. I have just one Table View with Search Bar
2. I populate when AppDidFinish with Call history plist
3. When the search bar isActive my App frezes until 2 millions rows loads. I need Avoid this step and move forward to step 4
4. Enter the search text. Then the result filteredArray has shown in the Table View

...

If have any idea I will appreciated.

Here you have some codes:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Guia" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"GuiaCache"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        abort();
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

Maybe in this method I need to improve with some Predicate

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)searchFetchRequest
{
    if (_searchFetchRequest != nil) {
        return _searchFetchRequest;
    }

    _searchFetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Guia" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [_searchFetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [_searchFetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:50];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [_searchFetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    return _searchFetchRequest;
}
```

Finaly the two functions to search in Core Data

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    if ([searchText length] > 3)
        [self searchForText:searchText scope:_scopeKeyIndex];
}

- (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSUInteger)scopeOption
{
    if (self.managedObjectContext)
    {
        NSString *predicateFormat = @"%K BEGINSWITH[cd] %@";
        NSString *searchAttribute = @"telephone";

        if (scopeOption == 1)
        {
            searchAttribute = @"name";
        }

        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:predicateFormat, searchAttribute, searchText];
        [self.searchFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        _filteredList = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.searchFetchRequest error:&error];
    }
}
```

If you need some other piece of code, just comment.

Comment: Your English is fine. How and why are you loading all rows? Show the code. Profile it in instruments.

Comment: Wain thanks for your comment. I dont want to load all rows. It's happen when I touch in the searchBar, then the controls frezed. I guest that the searchBarController load the Core Data preparing it self for the searchText entry. Maybe the solution are related with _numberofRowsInSection_. Later I will show some code.

Comment: I had riviewed the _numberOfRowsInSection_ and it's fine. Just get the count of my _filteredArrayOfSearch_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run Instruments against your application, specifically Time Profiler.  Where does it say the time is being spent?

Do you have a predicate in your search?  What does the predicate look like?  You need to show some code for people to help.

Doing a fetch against against 2 million records will take a bit of time but I suspect it is not loading 2 million rows into memory as that would most likely cause memory problems as well as speed problems.

Post the results from Time Profiler and lets see where the time is being spent.

### Update

First your predicate is very expensive.  `BEGINSWITH` should be avoided if at all possible.  Making it both case and diacritic insensitive increases that cost dramatically.

Did you run Instruments against your code?  Did you run the time profiler?  Without running that you are just guessing.  You **NEED** to run the time profiler and at least show the results if not link to the entire profile.

Comment: Dear Marcus Zarra, I hope this will not be impolite to you, for seeking a Core Data expert's help in such a manner, but I could not find other way to connect you. Could you spend some time upon my question here http://stackoverflow.com/q/24085507/889538 ? And if it's okay, may I have a way to contact you someday later? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Marcus, I'm working on predicate to limit my search I'm usign `BEGINWITH[cd]` but still load all rows in memory first. I will work hard to improve it, i will show code example soon.

Comment: `BEGINWITH[cd]` is about the slowest way you can find to filter in Core Data.  There are many other solutions that are far more efficient.  I would suggest that you consider de-normalizing your data so that you have a searchable property that avoids needing that particular part of the predicate.

Comment: And I guarantee you that it is not loading all rows into memory. It might be giving you back unrealized `NSManagedObject` instances but it is definitely not loading all rows.

Comment: Please Marcus, give me a review of my codes now when I was add it to the post. I understand the fact of the `BEGINWITH[cd]` as the slowest way, but i want to find a substring in a Person Name and also search for a phone number. In this last case the consecutive digits could be anywhere.