# CoreData: Same predicate (IN) returns different fetched results after a Save operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

## HUGE UPDATE：

I create a totally new project to mimic the problem, it does appear all the time!

Here is my data model:

[image]

[image]

`Task` has a to-many relationship pointing to `Person`.

```
@interface Person : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * personId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;

@end
```

//

```
@class Person;

@interface Task : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * taskId;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *watchers;
@end

@interface Task (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addWatchersObject:(Person *)value;
- (void)removeWatchersObject:(Person *)value;
- (void)addWatchers:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeWatchers:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

Now, I create two persons, p1 & p2, and two tasks, 1001 & 1002:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Person *p1 = [self insertOrUpdatePerson:@"111" withName:@"aaa"];
    Person *p2 = [self insertOrUpdatePerson:@"222" withName:@"bbb"];

    [self insertOrUpdateTask:1001 withWatcher:p1];
    [self insertOrUpdateTask:1001 withWatcher:p2];

    [self insertOrUpdateTask:1002 withWatcher:p1];
    [self insertOrUpdateTask:1002 withWatcher:p2];

    NSArray *watchedTasks = nil;

    watchedTasks = [self fetchTasksWatchedByPerson:p1]; // return 2 objects
    NSLog(@"watchedTasks : %@\n", watchedTasks);
    [self saveContext];
    watchedTasks = [self fetchTasksWatchedByPerson:p1]; // return 1 objects
    NSLog(@"watchedTasks : %@\n", watchedTasks);

    NSArray *allTasks = [self fetchAllTasks]; // return 2 objects
    NSLog(@"allTasks : %@\n", watchedTasks);
}
```

And the log follows. **Notice that the second output of watchedTasks has only one object!**

```
Printing description of watchedTasks:
<__NSArrayI 0x8d5aff0>(
<Task: 0x8d5b240> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d5b3e0 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p2> ; data: {
    taskId = 1002;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
}),
<Task: 0x8d59d10> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d59420 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p1> ; data: {
    taskId = 1001;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
})
)

Printing description of updateObjects:
<__NSArrayI 0x8e41880>(
<Task: 0x8d59d10> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d59420 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p1> ; data: {
    taskId = 1001;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
}),
<Task: 0x8d5b240> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d5b3e0 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p2> ; data: {
    taskId = 1002;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
}),
<Person: 0x8d56cc0> (entity: Person; id: 0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1> ; data: {
    name = aaa;
    personId = 111;
}),
<Person: 0x8d57be0> (entity: Person; id: 0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2> ; data: {
    name = bbb;
    personId = 222;
})
)

Printing description of watchedTasks:
<_PFArray 0x8f57da0>(
<Task: 0x8d5b240> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d5b3e0 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p2> ; data: {
    taskId = 1002;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
})
)

Printing description of allTasks:
<_PFArray 0x8e44b30>(
<Task: 0x8d59d10> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d59420 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p1> ; data: {
    taskId = 1001;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
}),
<Task: 0x8d5b240> (entity: Task; id: 0x8d5b3e0 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Task/p2> ; data: {
    taskId = 1002;
    watchers =     (
        "0x8d57f80 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p2>",
        "0x8d56070 <x-coredata://706EB8CA-ACE7-48DB-89E1-7CCFCDD41DA4/Person/p1>"
    );
})
)
(lldb)
```

So I open the .sqlite file to see what exactly in.

[image]

[image]

What surprise me first is that `watchers` is in the `Person` table, not in a middle/mapping `Task2Person` table. I remember that once the relationship exists in a middle table.

**Then, the `watchers` field in the `Person` table contains only one value, not a set or array!**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSArray *watchedTasks = nil;

    Person *p1 = [self insertOrUpdatePerson:@"111" withName:@"aaa"];
    Person *p2 = [self insertOrUpdatePerson:@"222" withName:@"bbb"];

    watchedTasks = [self fetchTasksWatchedByPerson:p1]; // return 1 object

    Task *t1 = [self insertOrUpdateTask:1001 withWatcher:p1]; // update watchers in the memory
    [self insertOrUpdateTask:1001 withWatcher:p2];

    Task *t2 = [self insertOrUpdateTask:1002 withWatcher:p1];
    [self insertOrUpdateTask:1002 withWatcher:p2];

    watchedTasks = [self fetchTasksWatchedByPerson:p1]; // return 2 objects

    [self saveContext];

    watchedTasks = [self fetchTasksWatchedByPerson:p1]; // return 1 object
```

So I found that after I launch the App and read the tasks from the db file, only 1 object is returned.

When I update the `watchers` information for the tasks, 2 objects can be fetched.

Finally after I save the context, only 1 object again.

---

## Just Ignore This

### - Old Information Below

I have code below:

```
        NSArray *existedTasks = [[TaskBizDB sharedInstance] fetchTasksWatchedByMeOfProject:projectId];
        [context save:&error];
        existedTasks = [[TaskBizDB sharedInstance] fetchTasksWatchedByMeOfProject:projectId];

        NSArray *allTasks = [[TaskBizDB sharedInstance] fetchTasksOfProject:projectId];
```

- First line returns **two objects**;
- Second line save the context;
- Third line returns **just one object**, which is contained in the 'two objects' above;
- And the last line returns 6 objects, **containing the 'two objects'**
  returned at the first line.

The fetch interface works like below:

```
WXModel *model = [WXModel modelWithEntity:NSStringFromClass([WQPKTeamTask class])];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ IN personWatchers) AND (projectId == %d)", currentLoginUser, projectId];
[model setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *fetchedTasks = [model fetch];
if (fetchedTasks.count == 0) return nil;

return fetchedTasks;
```

What confused me is that, with the same fetch request, why return different results just after a save?

Here comes more detail:

The 'two objects' returned at the first line are:

```
<WQPKTeamTask: 0x1b92fcc0> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0x1b9300f0 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p9> ; data: {
    projectId = 372004;
    taskId = 338001;
    personWatchers =     (
        "0xf0bf440 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WWPerson/p1>"
    );
}

<WQPKTeamTask: 0xf3f6130> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0xf3cb8d0 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p11> ; data: {
    projectId = 372004;
    taskId = 340006;
    personWatchers =     (
        "0xf0bf440 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WWPerson/p1>"
    );
}
```

And the only one object returned at third line is:

```
<WQPKTeamTask: 0x1b92fcc0> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0x1b9300f0 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p9> ; data: {
    projectId = 372004;
    taskId = 338001;
    personWatchers =     (
        "0xf0bf440 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WWPerson/p1>"
    );
}
```

Printing description of allTasks:

```
<_PFArray 0xf30b9a0>(
<WQPKTeamTask: 0xf3ab9d0> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0xf3cda40 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p6> ; data: <fault>),
<WQPKTeamTask: 0xf315720> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0xf3c23a0 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p7> ; data: <fault>),
<WQPKTeamTask: 0xf3a1ed0> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0xf3cda30 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p8> ; data: <fault>),
<WQPKTeamTask: 0x1b92fcc0> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0x1b9300f0 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p9> ; data: {
    projectId = 372004;
    taskId = 338001;
    personWatchers =     (
        "0xf0bf440 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WWPerson/p1>"
    );
}),
<WQPKTeamTask: 0xf325e50> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0xf343820 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p10> ; data: <fault>),
<WQPKTeamTask: 0xf3f6130> (entity: WQPKTeamTask; id: 0xf3cb8d0 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WQPKTeamTask/p11> ; data: {
    projectId = 372004;
    taskId = 340006;
    personWatchers =     (
        "0xf0bf440 <x-coredata://CFFD3F8B-E613-4DE8-85AA-4D6DD08E88C5/WWPerson/p1>"
    );
})
)
```

---

## UPDATE 1

If I call the same interface `fetchTasksWatchedByMeOfProject:` in:

```
#pragma mark - NSFetchedResultsController Delegate

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
```

I will get 'two objects' as well.

## UPDATE 2

I've tried:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY personWatchers == %@) AND (projectId == %d)", currentLoginUser, projectId];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY personWatchers.personId == %@) AND (projectId == %d)", currentLoginUserId, projectId];
```

Still the same result.

## UPDATE 3

I've checked the `save:&error`, error is nil.

Comment: Have you seen what the return value of `save:` is and whether the error is still nil?  (I don't see how it would matter, but there are two ways save can report an issue, and you're checking neither, at least in the code here.)

Comment: @stevesliva Thanks for tip. I've checked the `save:`, error is nil.

Comment: Point of clarity, you should only be looking at the result and then reacting to the error if the return is `YES`. Just looking at the error is insufficient and/or misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out this problem today with my teammates.

If you create a to-many relationship without inverse relationship, for example, `Task` has a to-many relationship `watchers` to `Person`, but `Person` doesn't have a inverse one to `Task`, then the relationship field `watchers` will be put in the `Person` table instead of a middle/mapping table.

Under this condition, my adding a `Person` p1 into the `Task` t1's `watchers` will update the `watchers` filed to `1` in the `Person` table.

Then, add `Person` p1 to the `Task` t2 as well, the `watchers` field will be update to `2` like below:

[image]

So, one `Person` can only point to one `Task`!

By adding a inverse relationship from `Person` to `Task` can walk around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is being saved?

What happens when you print out the `-[NSManagedObjectContext updatedObjects]` before the save?

What does the final predicate look like?  Can you print the description of the `NSFetchRequest`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I created a new project to locate the problem, and found some changes in the .sqlite file.